# no route maps to my action of my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a legacy Rails v2 project.

My project folder structure:

```
MyProj
 - app/
   - controllers/
     - api/
       - my_service/
          - products_controller.rb
          - manufactures_controller.rb
```

Inside *products_controller.rb*, I have a method (action) `def check_amount`.

In my routes.rb, I have defined:

```
api.namespace :my_service do |my_service|
      my_service.resources :products, :only =>[ :check_amount ]do |product|
        product.resources :manufactures, :only => [:create]
      end
    end
```

When I run rake routs , I can only see :

```
api_my_service_product_manufactures POST    /api/my_service/products/:product_id/manufactures(.:format)                   {:controller=>"api/my_service/products", :action=>"create"}
```

Why there is no route/path maps to the `check_amount` action of my *products_controller.rb* though I explicitly mentioned it in routes.rb configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `only` directive is for `RESTful` actions only `(INDEX|CREATE|UPDATE|DELETE)`

You can use `member` or `collection` instead:

- with `member`: You will have `/products/:id/check_amount` path
- with `collection`: You will have `/products/check_amount` path

```
api.namespace :my_service do |my_service|
  my_service.resources :products, :only =>[] do |product|
    get :check_amount, :on => :member
    product.resources :manufactures, :only => [:create]
      end
    end
  end
end
```